# Is it possible to generate mnemonic code from privatekey from web3j and bitcoin sdk

Tags: ethereum, web3-java

I am an Android developer and I try to import a wallet from its private key, everything goes well but there will no mnemonic code for this wallet, and I know private key comes from mnemonic code too. I only just wonder isn't possible to generate mnemonic code from the private key, I am new to Ethereum and need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this answer on the Eth Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62530/how-can-i-get-a-mnemonic-phrase-from-a-private-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private key corresponds to the an Ethereum address and public key. The mnemonic is, in general, used to derive a tree of public-private key pairs for `BIP39` format. Therefore, the private key to mnemonic conversion is technically, not possible. Otherwise it is a serious security issue.

For more information on how this generation work and what is a deterministic wallet, refer this answer [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/45978/what-is-the-wallet-word-seed-that-is-commonly-used-in-popular-wallets-clients?rq=1).